# how to print the number of triangle then print the minimum perimeter of it?

Tags: java

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
     public class project {
     public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);   

// to scan the values

    int N ;   

// numbers of lines

    double side1,side2,side3;  `




     double minimum = 1000; 

// to keep the minimum value

         double sum = 0;  

// to keep calculated values

          int which_one = 0 ;

    System.out.println("How many triangles do you have?");
    N = input.nextInt();         

// how many lines

     System.out.println("Please, insert lengths of the " 
            + "sides of these triangles (3 real numbers per line):");

            for (int i = 0; i < N ; i++){  

// loop for taking the value from the user


     side1 = input.nextDouble();           // input of side1
     side2 = input.nextDouble();           // input of side2
     side3 = input.nextDouble();           // input of side3
     sum = side1 + side2 + side3;  


     if (sum < minimum ) minimum = sum;
       which_one =  N+1;

            }

         System.out.printf("Triangle no."+ which_one 
              + " has the minimum perimeter which is %.1f%n "+minimum);        
}
}
```

Comment: Is there a question here?  Does your code work?  What are you asking us to do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in this line.  I have corrected it to what it should be:

```
System.out.printf("Triangle no." + which_one + 
    " has the minimum perimeter which is %.1f\n " , minimum);
```

I replaced the `+` before `minimum` with "," so that `minimum` is provided as the value for the format specifier `%.1f`.